# migrate Azure VM across subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blockchain-workbench

I am working on a VM in Azure. Recently Azure subscription is expired(disabled) & got a new subscription(For some reasons could not renew it).

Now trying to migrate my VM to the new subscription. How can I do it. 
Thanks in advance.

Tried downloading VHD(Virtual Hard Disk). Unable to create VM using this VHD.

VM Details:
Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS

Comment: When the subscription is expired, can you convert the vm disk into the ARM mode or cannot do any action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot move the resources from a disabled subscription. Please contact the [Azure billing support](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact/) *(it's free)*

[You can refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115985/move-azure-vm-to-other-subscription-in-other-region) on how to move the VM from one subscription to another ***(For an Active subscription)***

Comment: yes, unable to migrate my VM.
I created a VHD in old subscription.
can I create VM with this VHD in my new subscription.

Comment: @MuraliKrishna As long as the subscription is disabled you can't do the migration. You can refer my link in the answer for the creation of VM from the VHD