# Move SQL VM to CSP Subscription

Tags: azure, migration, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to move a VM which has azure back up running on recovery vault. Recovery vault is in a different resource group and my SQL VM is on a different RG. When i try moving to CSP subscription under same tenant i have an validation error.

> Error- The move resources request contains resources like ----- that
>   are being backed up as a part of a azure backup job.

I stopped the backup and tried moving to CSP, still i had the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Stopping the backup will not help. You need to remove any backup job before moving the Resources.  Stop the backup job remove it and try moving the resources.

Comment: Thank you Sajeetharan, I tried doing it and now i have an error.. The move resources does not contain all the dependent resources.....Missing Move Dependent resources.....Target/....

Comment: Ok , I'm not sure

Comment: Do you know if we can move unmanaged disk VM's to another subscription?

Comment: You can do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115985/move-azure-vm-to-other-subscription-in-other-region